# Django - Inline form for OneToOne field in admin site

Tags: python, django

Hi This question has been asked many times but unfortunately I could not find an answer for it that would actually work. Below are my models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class Address(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person)
    ...
```

Then in the admin I have:

```
class AddressInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Address


class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (AddressInline)

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

and then i get this infamous error:

```
<class 'address.models.Address'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'person.models.Person'>
```

I have tried:

- django-reverse-admin. Unfortunately did not work with Django 1.6 and I am not saavy enough to make it work with 1.6
- Several suggection in stackover flow on using proxy models and abstract base class and those did not work either.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me to find a workaround for it.

Comment: I've tried something similar in what I'm working on and the only difference I see is that I used a OneToOneField instead of OnetoOne. I'm not sure if you've used a field or a relation.

Comment: @vsachar: I used the OnetoOne relation

Comment: Could you please correct your code to use OneToOneField instead?

Comment: @vsachar: Sorry my ignorance, I don't understand OneToOneField. Admin module creates the field for OneToOne model relation automatically. Will you kindly explain where to use the OneToOneField.

Comment: Just replace the OneToOne in your code with OneToOneField in the models.py

Comment: @vsachar it is in fact OneToOneField, there is no OneToOne option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have not tried it, but this gist appears to be based on the code in django-reverse-admin but updated to work on Django 1.6:

https://gist.github.com/mzbyszewska/8b6afc312b024832aa85

Note that this part of the example code is wrong:

```
class AddressForm(models.Form):
    pass
```

...you need to `from django import forms` at the top and then do something like:

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
```

There's another problem in the example code here line #46:

```
inline_reverse = ('business_addr', ('home_addr', AddressForm), ('other_addr' (
    'form': OtherForm
    'exclude': ()
)))
```

should probably be:

```
inline_reverse = ('business_addr', ('home_addr', AddressForm), ('other_addr', {
    'form': OtherForm,
    'exclude': ()
}))
```

note that it shows you the three different ways to specify an inline... the first is just by field name `'business_addr'` i.e. if you don't need a custom form for the inline model.

Comment: I get an error as module' object has no attribute 'Form'. I followed the example that is provided in the comments of the code.

Comment: This seems to work even for django-1.8 but the custom form doesn't seem to work. It complains with error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' while registering admin.

Comment: I'd need to see more of the stack trace... also have a look at this gist https://gist.github.com/wolever/fdd36cbde02ca5cf085c which is forked from the original by someone who claims to make it work on Django 1.8

Comment: Here is the complete stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/U0zhPr7D. It is complaining because of the fields declared in reverse_inlines. I am not yet sure how to fix this. The problem is not django version incompatibility but the syntax for the inline_reverse values which it doesn't link.

Comment: I think I know what is happening I was passing like this:

inline_reverse = ( ('user', 'UserCreationForm') )

while it should have been:

inline_reverse = ( ('user', 'UserCreationForm'),  )

Though this solves the issue of unhashable type error but I don't see the UserCreationForm being used at all. I tried to put breakpoint in save method of form but it doesn't break there.

Comment: The form does get used if declared like this:

inline_revers = ( ('user', ({'form': UserCreationForm}), ), )

This is a bit confusing but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I have Installed:

- Django==1.6.5
- MySQL-python==1.2.4
- South==0.8.1

and the code below works form me:

models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Address(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

admin.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import *


class AddressInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Address


class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (AddressInline,)

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
admin.site.register(Address)
```

And this is the admin inferface:

[image: admin interface]

Comment: this is the best and simplest option, if the OP has the possibility of moving the `OneToOneField` onto the `Address` model instead of the `Person` model

Answer (score 0):

For those who looking solution for Django 2.0:
you can just use this library: https://pypi.org/project/django-reverse-admin/

It worked well for me.