# Django admin: Edit fields of one-to-one model class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have two models with the following relationship defined in models.py:

```
class InnerModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OuterModel(models.Model):
    inner = models.OneToOneField(InnerModel)

    def __str__(self):
        return "OuterModel"
```

My forms.py looks like this:

```
class OuterModelForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = OuterModel
        fields = ['inner']
```

My admin.py form looks like this:

```
class OuterModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    form = OuterModelForm

admin.site.register(OuterModel, OuterModelAdmin)
```

When I display the admin page, I can see the InnerModel instance and the name field is present, but the name field is an empty drop-down menu rather than a blank text field that can be edited.

How can I change the InnerModel name field so that it can be edited by admin?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `inlines` ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.inlines)):

```
class InnerModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = InnerModel

class OuterModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [InnerModelInline]

admin.site.register(OuterModel, OuterModelAdmin)
```

Similar question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623457/django-inline-form-for-onetoone-field-in-admin-site)

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without inlines?

Comment: Not that I know of, no.

Comment: Thank you - I should have specified the no-inline request in my question, I'd seen there are plenty of SO questions involving inlines.