# Django admin inline through one to one field

Tags: django, django-admin

`Item` has foreign key to `User` and `User` has `OneToOne` to `Profile`.

I have admin for `Profile`. How can I show all items as inlines?

I do not have foreign key from `Profile` to `Item`, so I need something like `user__itemset` but it seems it can't be used in Django admin.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? What do mean by inlines?

Comment: @DhavalSavalia Django admin has ``StackedInline`` and ``TabularInline``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - Inline form for OneToOne field in admin site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623457/django-inline-form-for-onetoone-field-in-admin-site)